# How to append or insert std::array elements into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdarray

I'm relatively new to c++ and I've tried to do some research, but while searching online I've mainly come across C arrays rather than `std::array`. What are the most efficient ways to append std::array elements into a std::vector, and to insert `std::array` elements into a `std::vector`? Should I use STL functions such as `std::copy`? I'm currently using C++17, MinGW64.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Appending" values can mean two things - you either want to copy/duplicate the elements in question, or you don't need them in the source container aftwards and might also move them into the destination container. Also, it makes sense to distinguish between insertion at construction time vs. appending to an existing, already constructed container: if you can, always construct a container with the elements that it's supposed to own.

1. Copy-append `std::array` elements to an already constructed `std::vector`:

   ```
   std::vector<T> dest;
   std::array<T, N> source;

   // ...

   dest.insert(dest.end(), source.cbegin(), source.cend());
   ```
2. Move-append `std::array`elements to an already constructed `std::vector`.

   ```
   std::vector<T> dest;
   std::array<T, N> source;

   // ...

   dest.insert(dest.end(), std::move_iterator(source.begin()),
               std::move_iterator(source.end()));
   ```
3. Copy `std::array` elements into a `std::vector` at construction:

   ```
   std::array<T, N> source;

   // ...

   std::vector<T> dest(source.cbegin(), source.cend());
   ```
4. Move `std::array` elements into a `std::vector` at construction:

   ```
   std::array<T, N> source;

   // ...

   std::vector<T> dest(std::move_iterator(source.begin()),
                       std::move_iterator(source.cend()));
   ```

There is not much to add here when talking about insertion into the middle - the only notable difference is that it will always be less efficient, as the remaining elements in the destination `std::vector` will be move-constructed (which is O(N)).

Note also that for appending elements, there is `std::move` and `std::copy` from the `<algorithm>` header  (where `std::copy` can be used with `std::move_iterator`s). However, these cannot be as efficient as a direct call to `std::vector::insert`, because the former operates on the iterator abstraction and processes the copy/move one element at a time without knowing about the storage details of the destination (this can result in multiple buffer resizings), while the latter is a `std::vector` member function and will resize the buffer only once (if required).

Answer (score 11):

To append the elements of an existing array (or other range in general) to a vector you can just use the vector's insert overload for an iterator range:

```
   vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
   array<int, 3> arr{4, 5, 6};
   // arr could be some other container or bare array as well, for ex.:
   // int arr[] = {4, 5, 6};
   // vector<int> arr {4, 5, 6};
   // list<int> arr {4, 5, 6};
   // ...
   
   vec.insert(vec.end(), begin(arr), end(arr));  // insert at vec.end() = append
  //or  vec.insert(vec.end(), arr.begin(), arr.end());  // insert at vec.end() = append
```

Note that if you have some other type instead of `int` which is expensive to copy, and you **want to move** the elements **from the source array**, you can use
`move_iterator`, for ex.

```
vec.insert(vec.end(), move_iterator(arr.begin()), move_iterator(arr.end()));
```

**For operations on ranges** in general, the **container member functions** are to be **preferred** instead of the same-named functions from the `<algorithm>` header.

So for example in this case the `vec.insert` will insert the range at once, as opposed if have had used the `std::insert` where the elements would be inserted one by one.

This is very nice explained in the Scott Meyers *Effective STL*.

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51c5160d4b2c88ef)

Comment: Note to reader that this is the exactly same way as one would add elements of a bare array into a vector as well, or elements of a linked list for that matter. Any input range will do.

Comment: Could also use move iterators, depending on the type.